# Taking a ball from $n$ balls in an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

I am dealing with this question and I don't know from where I should begin.

Consider an urn containing $n$ balls numbered from $1$ to $n$. An experiment
consists in drawing a ball at random and noting its number.

For each divisor $\alpha$ of $n$ we denote by $c$ the event "the drawn ball bears a number divisible by $\alpha$". Compute $P(\alpha)$.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To compute $P(\alpha)$, the probability that the drawn ball bears a number divisible by $\alpha$, we first need to know the number of balls in the urn that are divisible by $\alpha$.

Let's call the set of all divisors of $n$, $D(n)$, and let's denote by $d$ the number of elements in $D(n)$. Now, let's define a function $F(\alpha)$ that counts the number of balls divisible by $\alpha$:

$$F(\alpha) = |{x : 1 \leq x \leq n, x \text{ is divisible by } \alpha}|$$

The probability of drawing a ball divisible by $\alpha$ is the ratio of the number of balls divisible by $\alpha$ to the total number of balls in the urn:

$$P(\alpha) = F(\alpha) / n$$

To compute $F(\alpha)$, we can simply count how many times $\alpha$ divides the numbers from 1 to $n$. For example, if $\alpha = 1$, then $F(1) = n$, as all numbers from 1 to $n$ are divisible by 1. In the general case, we can use the following formula to compute $F(\alpha)$:

$$F(\alpha) = \lfloor n / \alpha \rfloor$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Now, we can substitute $F(\alpha)$ in our probability formula:

$$P(\alpha) = F(\alpha) / n = \lfloor n / \alpha \rfloor / n$$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.

Comment: I am doing maths here. There is a question, and I was interested in answering. I do not see a reason not to answer because you dislike. There are ways in accordance to policy that you can intervene if you claim low standard of question. End of discussion.

Comment: You may misunderstand. Gary is not indicating a personal dislike. It is against current practice (and possibly explicit policy—I'm not sure about that) to answer questions that are simple problem-statement questions (PSQ). This practice is intended (at least in part) to discourage people from posting homework questions in order to get cheap answers. Your answer, even though it may be correct, works against the quality of questions submitted to the site.

Comment: In addition, your "End of discussion" suggests a hostility to discussion that is antithetical to the spirit of Math.SE. It's possible you're not aware of this connotation (e.g., if English is not your first language), but I do encourage you to avoid giving that impression if you can, thanks! ¶ Incidentally, I did not down-vote your answer, but the down-votes are probably in response to your answering a PSQ.

Comment: I apologize if that might be understood that wrong way. I intended to say that I from my side will not continue to discuss on this matter, since I believe my objective answer to a maths question cannot be judged by subjective opinions, related to the policies of the forum. We have clear processes here for how to claim policies, and disliking answers is not the way: "Instead of answering it" is actually intimidating.